# Object with more than one Model (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, model

**BACKGROUND:** 
I'm thinking conceptually about how to reference a single object that can belong to more than one model. For instance, if I have a School and Employer model - a User could theoretically have attended and be employed at the same School. Ideally both relationships to point to the same object.

**QUESTION:**
How would I model that in a postgresql-based Rails app?

**UPDATE**
In this case, I'd need a user to be able to have both one or more Schools and one or more Employers.

Comment: Not a rails guy, but wouldn't you have a user model with two properties with are both school models?

Comment: How are School and Employer related?

Comment: @sean In the way I'm thinking about it, they aren't related, except that one object can be both a School and an Employer at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: To reflect that the question was about HABTM

You'd use something like this if you want to be able to use the same exact record for both Employer and School in `User.employer`. I'm assuming a User can only have one School and one Employer, no more.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employees, as: :employable
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students, class_name: "User"
end

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employees, as: :employable
end

class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base #This object models the relationship between User and Employer
    belongs_to :employer, as: :employable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :user


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :schools
    has_many :contracts
    has_many :employers, through: :contracts
end
```

this would set it up so that if you call `User.school` it would return a School object, but if you call `User.employer` it could go to either School or Employer depending on what User points to.

This makes use of [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Please read about them as the Migrations are different for this kind of association.

The reason we're using a `Contract` object is that a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association can't be polymorphic, so we to roll that out manually. If you don't like `has_and_belongs_to_many` or need more flexibility for the `School` relationship, you could use an intermediary object like for employer, maybe called `Tuition`.

Comment: Only addition I'd add is consider the case of a user that has no school or no employer.

Comment: That case doesn't change the required code at all though? Employer and school would be nil, that's it

Comment: Sorry for not specifying - in this case, I'd need a user to be able to have both one or more Schools and one or more Employers

Comment: @neon check it out now, this should help you on your way. Please note my code probably won't work out of the box, I wrote this by hand without testing. It's more to show you the way to go

Answer (score 1):

To do this you would have three models, User, School and Employer.

The User `belongs_to`one School and `belongs_to` one Employer.
The School `has_many` Users.
The Employer `has_many` Users.

Knowing these relations, which are used directly in your models, you now know that the User will have a `school_id` and an `employer_id` attribute.  Neither the School nor the Employer will have a `user_id`.

If you decide to go down the route of users having and belonging to many Schools or Employers (`has_and_belongs_to_many`) then you will want to look at the ActiveRecord documentation on join tables.